Отправка большого файла через телеграм бота
Пытаюсь отправить через телеграм бота видео, размером более 50мб. Видео меньшего размера отправляются без проблем, но большего нет - выдает ошибку. Пишет, что " Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение". Если ли способы как обойти эту ошибку?
Отправку видео реализую следующим образом
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead("C:\CbFiles\Определения\\Видео\\Video.mp4"))
{
    var video = new InputFileStream(fileStream, "Video.mp4");

    await botClient.SendVideoAsync(callbackQuery.Message.Chat.Id, video: video);
}


https://stackoverflow.com/a/68388683/12888024

@aepot, спасибо! Почему-то не натыкался на данный вопрос
